# Cómo Buscar en DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel, datagridview

Necesito buscar en un excel cargado a un `DataGridView` pero al poner el nombre del excel en el campo me da error por tener conflictos con otros nombres y diferentes hojas pero mismo excel

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Este código funciona, pero por que una hoja tiene como nombre de su columna "Nombre"
el problema es que otra hoja del mismo excel no posee `Nombre` así que para que funcionara no solo tuve que dejar en comentario el primer código que mostró, si no poner de valor "Column4"

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Column4 LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text)
```

El punto es que ambos funcionan pero solo si no esta el otro, preguntaba si **existe una manera de poder buscar con ambos?**

Ya que necesito que ambos funcionen ademas **si es posible un buscador en el que no sea necesario mencionar el nombre de la columna.**

Comment: Una idea: _Puedes hacer que si necesitas buscar por la columna `Nombre` des un click en el `Header` y ahí obtienes el nombre de la columna `DataPropertyName`, lo asignas a una variable del formulario, y pasas esas variable al string del filtro. Y cuando quieras buscar por la otra columna das click en la otra columna y ya puedes filtrar por ella_. Ahora en código sería esto: `string NombreColumna = "";
private void tuGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
 NombreColumna  = tuGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName.Trim();
        }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como te puse en mi comentario, podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

**Método 1:**

Primero obtienes el nombre de la columna por la que deseas filtrar dando click en el `Header` de cada columna, para obtener el nombre de la propiedad `DataPropertyName`:

```
string nombre_columna = ""; 
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
   nombre_columna = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName.Trim(); 
}
```

Luego podrías hacer una función que se encargue de hacer el filtrado de los datos, así:

```
private void FiltrarDatosDatagridview(DataGridView datagrid, string nombre_columna, TextBox txt_buscar)
{
     ///Al texto recibido si contiene un asterisco (*) lo reemplazo de la cadena
     ///para que no provoque una excepción.
     string cadena = txt_buscar.Text.Trim().Replace("*", "");
     string filtro = string.Format("convert([{0}], System.String) LIKE '{1}%'",nombre_columna,cadena);

     ///A la vista del DataGridView con la propiedad RowFilter
     ///se le asigna la cadena del filtro para mostrarla en el DataGridView
     (datagrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro;
}
```

Y para usar esta función lo haces de esta manera en el evento `TextChanged` de tu `TextBox`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     FiltrarDatosDatagridview(dataGridView1, nombre_columna, textBox1);
}
```

---

Una validación que puedes hacer es: `string nombre_columna = "Nombre";` tenga un valor por defecto, por si el usuario no ha dado click a una columna y desea buscar al desde que cargue el formulario...

> Quizás debas tomar en cuenta otras validaciones necesarias, esto solo es una idea rápido que me llega a la mente...

---

**Método 2:**

Otra solución para lo que buscas es esta, recorrer todas las columnas y así asignarlas a la cadena de filtrado de esta manera:

```
StringBuilder filtro = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro.ToString()))
     {
         filtro.Append($"{dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name} LIKE '{textBox1.Text}%'");
     }
     else
     {
         filtro.Append(" OR ");
         filtro.Append($"{dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name} LIKE '{textBox1.Text}%'");
     }
}
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filtro.ToString();
```

Comment: actualmente busco que encuentre en toda las columnas pero me da conflicto en las hojas, es decir el excel tiene 4 hojas , en 3 de estas, esta Nombre como titulo de sus columnas , pero una de las hojas del excel, no tiene nombre de columna por esos solo cuenta como Column1 o independiente del numero , pero yo necesito que busque todas las columnas de todas las hojas a base de un textbox_textchanged, por eso mi duda es si es posible no especifiar el nombre de la columna al momento de buscar o si existe una forma en que e buscador no me de conflico y pueda buscar todas las columnas del excel

Comment: @nerocaos Hola, en los controles oficiales de `WinForms` **no conozco una manera filtrar sin especificar a que columna deseas filtrar**, esto si podría hacerse usando controles de terceros como `DevExpress  - GridView` que trae esta funcionalidad y va de maravilla... Pero como te digo: _"Esta idea que te propuse te funcionará para lo que deseas, con la condición de que debes hacer click en la columna que desees filtrar"_..

Comment: probare, gracias, pero no deseo filtrar una deseo que se pueda buscar todo

Comment: @nerocaos revisa mi respuesta, la he editado, he agregado otra manera en la que puedes filtrar todas las columnas...

Comment: disculpa a que se refiere con el column.name? y creo que esta forma puede servir se me habia olvidado probar con OR

Comment: Al nombre que se obtiene desde la fuente de datos, puede usar también `column.DataPropertyName`

Comment: raro, no me da la opcion para DataPropertyName,

Comment: @nerocaos Disculpe mi error de sintaxis, estoy trabajando con la mente, y no en un compilador, he editado la respuesta, revise, ya puede usar `Name` y `DataPropertyName`

Comment: funciono para las que tienen por nombre Column pero sigue el problema de dar conflicto con las que tienen un nombre definido, talves si en el else declaro las de nombre definido funciono

Comment: @nerocaos Ya esas serían validaciones que tu como programador debes controlar a tu caso especifico. Me alegra haber sido de ayuda, si te ha funcionado podría considerar [votar a favor a la respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) y marcar la [respuesta como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/69447) para que la pregunta quede como concluida.